# SOAP-to-REST translation in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, asp.net-core, soap, translation

Most of our bespoke applications in AWS are containerized .NET Core apps and so far we haven't needed to build any SOAP APIs - virtually all of the APIs that we've delivered (whether exposed publicly via AWS API Gateway or internal only) are JSON RPC following a RESTful architecture/design principles.

We also have a third party COTS product deployed into our AWS account that produces SOAP webhooks and we need to receive and process these SOAP webhooks produced by the third party COTS product.

Ideally we don't want to build a bespoke SOAP API / translation layer - even if WCF is now supported in .NET Core / 5+, I'd much rather we just stick with HTTP/REST and .NET Core WebAPIs which is well understood by our delivery teams. Ideally there is a way e.g. a native AWS service, that would allow us to translate the SOAP request to a HTTP/REST request. Does anyone know if there's a native AWS service with these capabilities?

Cheers.

Comment: There is no service with the functionality that you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

The translation would be something like the following

```
HTTP method GET/POST + SOAP operation verb endpoint
POST /soap/cancelOrder <message>{id}</message>

<=>

HTTP method GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE + REST resource noun endpoint
DELETE /rest/orders/{id}
```

Without a naming convention it is hard to translate. Another issue here, that real REST services return hypermedia with a flexible structure, while SOAP services return SOAP message with a ridig structure defined in WSDL. Yet another issue that SOAP is stateful, while REST is stateless.

Maybe in edge cases it is possible to automatically translate for example by services which do only basic CRUD without any real business logic.